# include gturri android xml rpc library in android project

Tags: java, android, xml, maven, xml-rpc

i need to include this library but i ve got several problems. 
[project library on github](https://github.com/gturri/aXMLRPC)

i tried to follow the instructions on the github project but they did not work for me. I have to include the library in android studio.

i tried to:
1) copy the whole code in my project but i had a lot of conflicts about package, and, once solved, i began to have problems about lacks of functions not defined
2) i tried to use mvn install command, but it did not work, something like 100 errors displayed 
3) i tried to open that project with intelliJ and then i tried to export jar file, but intelliJ told that it s an android project

does anyone have any idea about the procedure to include this library? 
Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could give Jitpack a try. At least it worked for me..

See https://jitpack.io/

In essence: add following code to the build.gradle file of your project:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}
```

and add the following line to the dependencies section in the build.gradle file of your app:

```
`compile 'com.github.gturri:aXMLRPC:master-SNAPSHOT'`
```

here is what the dependency section looks like for me:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.github.gturri:aXMLRPC:master-SNAPSHOT'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
```

}