# ODOO How to create many2one record from Android Studio using aXMLRPC library?

Tags: java, android, odoo

I am trying to create a new record in **fleet.vehicle** model. Since the **Type** of record is **Many2One**, it throws the following exception.

```
de.timroes.axmlrpc.XMLRPCServerException: Traceback (most recent call last):
```

However I was able to create a record in **res.user** model with the same code snippet because the **Type** was char for **res.user** model.
My code Snippet is:

```
public Integer create(String model, HashMap values) {
        Integer newObjectId = null;
        try {

            XMLRPCClient client = new XMLRPCClient(mUrl);

            Object[] parameters = {mDatabase, mUserId, mPassword, model, "create" ,new Object[]{values}};
            newObjectId = (Integer) client.call("execute_kw", parameters);

        } catch (XMLRPCException e) {
            Log.d(CONNECTOR_NAME, e.toString());
        }
        return newObjectId;
    }
```

and the log is:

```
de.timroes.axmlrpc.XMLRPCServerException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/wms/RMS/9040/new_odoo11/odoo/service/wsgi_server.py", line 124, in wsgi_xmlrpc
    result = odoo.http.dispatch_rpc(service, method, params)
  File "/home/wms/RMS/9040/new_odoo11/odoo/http.py", line 115, in dispatch_rpc
    result = dispatch(method, params)
  File "/home/wms/RMS/9040/new_odoo11/odoo/service/model.py", line 39, in dispatch
    res = fn(db, uid, *params)
  File "/home/wms/RMS/9040/new_odoo11/odoo/service/model.py", line 153, in execute_kw
    return execute(db, uid, obj, method, *args, **kw or {})
  File "/home/wms/RMS/9040/new_odoo11/odoo/service/model.py", line 97, in wrapper
    return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/wms/RMS/9040/new_odoo11/odoo/service/model.py", line 160, in execute
    res = execute_cr(cr, uid, obj, method, *args, **kw)
  File "/home/wms/RMS/9040/new_odoo11/odoo/service/model.py", line 149, in execute_cr
    return odoo.api.call_kw(recs, method, args, kw)
  File "/home/wms/RMS/9040/new_odoo11/odoo/api.py", line 687, in call_kw
    return call_kw_model(method, model, args, kwargs)
  File "/home/wms/RMS/9040/new_odoo11/odoo/api.py", line 672, in call_kw_model
    result = method(recs, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/wms/RMS/9040/new_odoo11/addons/fleet/models/fleet_vehicle.py", line 197, in create
    vehicle = super(FleetVehicle, self.with_context(mail_create_nolog=True)).create(data)
  File "/home/wms/RMS/9040/ac-ars/ac_rms/models/planner_calender.py", line 422, in create
    res_id = super(MailThread, self).create(values)
  File "/home/wms/RMS/9040/new_odoo11/addons/mail/models/mail_thread.py", line 231, in create
    thread = super(MailThread, self).create(values)
  File "/home/wms/RMS/9040/new_odoo11/odoo/models.py", line 3278, in create
    record = self.browse(self._create(old_vals))
  File "/home/wms/RMS/9040/new_odoo11/odoo/models.py", line 3371, in _create
    cr.execute(query, tuple(u[2] for u in updates if len(u) > 2))
  File "/home/wms/RMS/9040/new_odoo11/odoo/sql_db.py", line 155, in wrapper
    return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/wms/RMS/9040/new_odoo11/odoo/sql_db.py", line 232, in execute
    res = self._obj.execute(query, params)
psycopg2.DataError: invalid input syntax for integer: "Audi A3"
LINE 1: ...et_vehicle_id_seq'), 5, true, 'kilometers', NULL, 'Audi A3',...
 [1]
```

I have attached a image as well of what I am trying to create. Any help is much appreciated.   [image]
My question is how to create a new record of type **Many2One** from Android/Java in odoo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am answering my own question. The answer for this problem is very simple which I found out exploring, debugging and trying things out with XMLRPC library. This is how I solved it.
The field I was trying to update only accepts the data that is already preset in odoo. For example: I had to first search for the available preset data for that field by using search_read functionality. Like..

```
OdooConnect oc = OdooConnect.connect(SERVER_URL, PORT_NO, DB_NAME, USER_ID, PASSWORD);
List<HashMap<String, Object>> data = oc.search_read("fleet.vehicle", new Object[]{
                new Object[]{condition}}, "id");
```

What I am doing here is searching for all the preset data related to the field I want to create and get the id of the string that matches with the one I want to update with certain conditions.
here condition is

```
new Object[]{new Object[]{new Object[]{"name", "=", "Audi A3"}}}
```

so when it matches with that condition, it returns the id of the object I need to pass  to the many2one field. 
In the above code **"id"** is for asking for an id of the string that matched the condition.
Now we will pass the id while creating a new record to many2one field. Pass the id to below create method.

```
final Integer idC = oc.create("web.service", new HashMap() {{
                put("name", "Final Test");
                put("value", 29); //
                put("partner_id", id); //many2One field. here we are using pre defined value i,e setting a value of other relation model to partner_id
        }});
```

Hope it helps someone who is looking for an answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

From the traceback `sycopg2.DataError: invalid input syntax for integer: "Audi A3"` is saying you passing a non-integer value. Just replace `Audi A3` with id. Then try again.

Hope it will help you.

Comment: I really do not know how to fetch ID and replace it instead of "Audi A3". I tried replacing "Audi A3" with a number manually without any kind of search. It gives another error.
`de.timroes.axmlrpc.XMLRPCException: Error getting result from server."`

Comment: I appreciate your time @KbiR. I have searched a lot for some sample java/android examples. But none explains how to create Many2One field. If you can give me a simple example on that it would be really helpful. I am sorry I am new to Odoo.